# flush or reset codeigniter active records without execute after build?

Tags: codeigniter, activerecord

Actually i saw some suggestions in stackoverflow itself but didnt get the exact solution for this issue, Please dont think this is a duplicate.

Am using memcache for my codeigniter site and active records to build query.
Am using

```
    this->db->return_query_string();
```

to get the query from active records before executing .Now i want to flush the active records with out executing the same query.

also from various references

```
     $this->db->start_cache();
     $this->db->stop_cache();
     $this->db->flush_cache()
```

may do the job is this is the exact result? if so how can i get the cached query with out execute

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use these two functions for your requirements

```
public function _compile_select($select_override = FALSE)
public function _reset_select()
```

To use them you will have to remove public or private keywords.
Go to system/database/DB_active_rec.php Remove public or protected keyword from these functions

Example usage

```
$this->db->select('trans_id');
$this->db->from('myTable');
$this->db->where('code','B');
$subQuery = $this->db->_compile_select();

$this->db->_reset_select();
```

$subQuery contains the query string and _reset_select resets the active record so you can write a new query.

Answer (score 3):

Starting from CodeIgniter 3.x, you can do:

```
$subQuery = $this->db
    ->select('trans_id')
    ->where('code', 'B')
    ->get_compiled_select('myTable');
```